# Router links in view not updating after re-navigation

Tags: aurelia

I have list of agents and want to do something with each of them. For "doing something" i have view with list of agents, nested parent view, that handles navigation, and set of child views, representing navigation.

Most top-level view viewmodel:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.title = 'Agents';
    config.map([
        { route: '', name: 'dummy', moduleId: 'components/agents-components/dummy', nav: false },
        { route: ':id', name: 'agent', moduleId: 'components/agents-components/agent-details', nav: false }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
```

View "dummy" displays when no agent is selected.

Agent-details view viewmodel:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.title = '';
    config.map([
        { route: 'info', name: 'agent-info', moduleId: 'components/agents-components/agent-info', title: 'Info', nav: true },
        { route: 'add', name: 'agent-add', moduleId: 'components/agents-components/agent-add', title: 'Add', nav: true }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
```

And html:

```
<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
    <a href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
</li>
```

Url scheme is something like /agents/764/info or /agents/764/add

After clicking on agent #764 i'm displaying route 'info' from agent-details view and using

```
activate(params) {
    this.id = params.id;
}
```

to obtain agent's id. Everything works so far, links in agent-details view is correct and contain current agent's id (/agents/764/info and /agents/764/add), i could select tab "add" and do something.

But then i'm clicking at other agent, url in address bar becomes /agents/765/info, and in info's activate(params) i'm getting correct id. But configureRouter of agent-details view not calling and links in html still /agents/764/info and /agents/764/add . So when i'm clicking at link "Add" i'm going to add view of previous agent.

How could i fix it? Is there any way to force re-render of agent-details view? Or i should manually fix routes in agent-details activate() or even bind links in html to manually created properties instead of router.navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force router configuring just add to Agent-details viewmodel:

```
import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router';
...
determineActivationStrategy(){
  return activationStrategy.replace;
}
```